# How to caption a tabular in a subfloat?

Tags: tables, captionof

I am trying to caption my table included as a subfigure using the subfloat. I used `\captionof` but it pops errors. Can anyone help me please?

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{
    \label{tab-travelplansymbols}
    \begin{adjustbox}{scale=0.7,valign=b}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l}

         \hline
         \multirow{2}{*}{State}&
         \multirow{2}{*}{Traveler Action}&
         \multirow{2}{*}{Guard}&
         \multirow{2}{*}{Description}\\
         &&&\\
         \hline
         \faHome & Staying Home & \faBellO,\faBellSlashO & Phone ringing,silent\\
         \faBed & Sleeping & \faClockO & Traffic delay\\
         \faChild & Waking up & \faThumbsOUp & ID approved\\
         \faCoffee & Having Coffee & \faMoonO & Normal weather\\
         \faBus & Taking bus & \faFlash & Adverse weather\\
         \faArrowCircleRight & Check-in & &\\
         \faMapMarker & Airport & &\\
         \faPlane & Flight & &\\
         \faHourglass & Oversleeping & &\\
         \faInternetExplorer & Online ticket purchase & &\\
         \faTaxi & Taking taxi & &\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\captionof{table}{Travel plan description.}

    \end{adjustbox}
   
    }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: \subfloat puts the caption into the optional argument.  Might be a good idea to put the label in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no reason for using a `figure` environment to typeset the table at hand. I'd use a `table` environment instead, allowing me to do away with the `subfigure` overhead along the way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering
\caption{Travel plan description}
\label{tab-travelplansymbols}

\smallskip
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}}
\toprule
State & Traveler Action & Guard & Description \\
\midrule
\faHome & Staying Home & \faBellO,\faBellSlashO & Phone ringing,silent\\
\faBed & Sleeping & \faClockO & Traffic delay\\
\faChild & Waking up & \faThumbsOUp & ID approved\\
\faCoffee & Having Coffee & \faMoonO & Normal weather\\
\faBus & Taking bus & \faFlash & Adverse weather\\
\faArrowCircleRight & Check-in & &\\
\faMapMarker & Airport & &\\
\faPlane & Flight & &\\
\faHourglass & Oversleeping & &\\
\faInternetExplorer & Online ticket purchase & &\\
\faTaxi & Taking taxi & &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to have another subfloat with another figure in it, which is why I used `figure` environment. I want to have a table as a subfigure alongside couple of other figures and want to caption the table, too.

Comment: @Mostafa - Thanks for providing this additional information. Please edit your original posting to include these important pieces of information.